# Which numbers are square modulo 9?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

How can I prove that n = $1,4,7,9$ for every integer k such that $k^2 = n$ (mod9)?

Comment: Square everybody from $0$ to $8$. Actually to $4$ will do, for the second half never  gives anything new.

Answer (score 5):

You would better state it using $0$ instead of $9$, i.e., $\forall{k}:k^2\equiv0,1,4,7\pmod9$.

---

There you go:

- $k\equiv0\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv0^2\equiv0\pmod9$
- $k\equiv1\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv1^2\equiv1\pmod9$
- $k\equiv2\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv2^2\equiv4\pmod9$
- $k\equiv3\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv3^2\equiv9\equiv0\pmod9$
- $k\equiv4\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv4^2\equiv16\equiv7\pmod9$
- $k\equiv5\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv5^2\equiv25\equiv7\pmod9$
- $k\equiv6\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv6^2\equiv36\equiv0\pmod9$
- $k\equiv7\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv7^2\equiv49\equiv4\pmod9$
- $k\equiv8\pmod9 \implies k^2\equiv8^2\equiv64\equiv1\pmod9$

Comment: This is the best answer. Fully described and absolutely substantial.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Thanks (it is also the worst answer at the moment, since it's the only answer).

Comment: When such an answer has been posted, it will be needless to post another answer as the person who asked this, will surely make this out, even if he/she is a newcomer in the field of congruence theory.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey: Thanks again :)

Comment: @barakmanos why do you use this symbol ≡ instead of =. I read that ≡ means that the modulo operator applied to both members gives the same result. A ≡ B is equivilant to A mod(n) = B mod(n).

Comment: @Mathguy007: That is exactly why I've used it. I could also write it (for example) as $5^2\color\red=25\equiv7\pmod9$, but it doesn't mean that the notation above is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

k^2 = n mod 9

I would start with observing that for any integer k, k=9a+b where b=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8 and a is any integer.

so, k^2 = (81 a^2 + 18ab + b^2) = b^2 mod 9

So possible solutions for n are 0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64 = 0,1,4,0,7,7,4,1 mod 9 = 0,1,4,7 mod 9